# JavaScript не отправляется запрос

Tags: javascript, api

Не получается отправить запрос, выдает ошибку: "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

```js
let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
});

let result = await response.json();
console.log(result.message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` можно использовать только внутри асинхронных функций (есть некоторые исключения — консоль браузера, ES модули в Node.js последних версий). Вы можете обернуть код в сразу исполняемую асинхронную функцию (IIAFE):

```js
(async function main() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      },
    });

    let result = await response.json();
    console.log(result.message);    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Спасбио! Но теперь возникает следущая ошибка: TypeError: "https://sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/?query=Board%20Testamex%20Web:%20%7B2%20sprint%7D%20State:%20%7BNeed%20testing%7D" is not a function

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит создать новый вопрос с этой ошибкой и обновлённым минимизированным примером кода, который её производит.